# User with saved Windows profile not able to login remotely

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, domain, login, user-profile

When we set up computers, we always connect it to our company domain after we add the user into our Active Directory. So the next time we reboot the system we can login with the user credentials since we haved joined it to the domain.

Usually, once we sign in with the user credentials Windows (Windows 7) automatically saves the profile. So if the user not connected to the LAN, they can just log in on the computer with the credentials without any problem since Windows has the user profile saved.

The issue now is that we have a user that not able to log onto the computer remotely even though he was able in the office. He gets the following error when trying to log in without being connected to the LAN:

> There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.

I am pretty sure this happens when the is not domain found.

But this error shouldn't come up since he has signed in before and should have a user profile saved on the system. So my question is: How does a user profile just disappear? An is there a way for me to assist the person since he is a not connected to the LAN?

Comment: Cached domain credentials are only good for a certain period of time, after which the user needs to re-connect to the domain.

Comment: @EEAA: I don't think that's the case. I've never heard of cached Domain credentials expiring. I wonder what would happen if the OP has the user disconnect from their network and try logging in with their Domain credentials.

Comment: @lwilliams: how is the client configured for DNS when they're not on your AD network? What happens if they disconnect from their network and try to log in?

Comment: @joeqwerty sorry for the later response the user is on our AD, because he was able to sign in normally when he went into the office today (6/17/15). So I not to sure why he wasn't able to sign in at the hotel he was staying at. Normally once you sign into the system connected to our domain it caches the user profile, so he can login whether he is in the office or work someplace remotely. I will tell him to see if the user can log in at a remote location and see if the issue still persists.  I will update you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen if the user connects to a network where the laptop thinks it should see the domain controller and doesn't. I don't remember the specifics, but it was either a customer network where the DNS server was Windows but obviously didn't know how to reach the correct DC, or the network had the same 172.168 subnet as the DC, but the DC wasn't reachable.

The solution was to log in disconnected, then connect to the network after logging in. Most laptops have a hardware switch for turning off wireless on an airplane.